# Why no bracha acharona for wine drunk with a bread meal?

Tags: halacha, blessing, grapes-wine, meal-seudah

Why do we say a separate bracha rishona for wine (borei pri hagafen) when we have wine with a bread meal, but we do not say a separate bracha acharona for the wine (that is, the wine is covered by the birchat hamazon)?

Comment: Incidentally I believe it's a machloket, and thus part of the reason for saying birkat hamazon over  a cos.

Answer (score 1):

Not only does Birchas Hamazon work for wine when drunk during a meal, but even if a person accidentally says Birchas Hamazon on a cup of wine it also works.

The Mishna Berurah in ziman 208 #76 explains that wine satiates  זיין וסועד הלב like bread, so the bracha of הזן works.

This same rule applies to dates.

Comment: Any thoughts on the reason for the separate bracha rishona for wine, even after saying hamotzi?

Comment: You have a good question because the reason to give wine a special bracha and not leave it as haetz is because of this very reason of satisfying and satiating, however technically the bracha rishona on bread mentions lechem, this does not include wine.

Comment: Yes, but the bracha on bread covers all the food in the meal, except wine (and non-meal foods/drink).  So I am still searching for a reason.